# Installing Magento locally with MAMP

Tags: magento, local, mamp

I have been trying to install the latest version of Magento community locally on a MAC but it does not appear to be working.

- I have downloaded the latest ZIP version
- I have created a database in phpMyAdmin and imported the sample data
- I have extracted the ZIP files and pasted them into the MAMP/htdocs/magento directory
- When I navigate to 127.0.0.1/magento/ I get the following error:

The requested URL /magento/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

I do not have a PRO version of MAMP so it is the only thing I can think of. I have seen different (old) posts with people with similar errors, none which have fixed my problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

not port 80, port 8888 for mamp is default. You may well need to change the version of PHP running, you can do this when you run the MAMP app- I am not sure you are doing that either! (although you do say you used phpmyadmin, so maybe you are).

(Run /Applications/Mamp app and you get a little control window that lets you start stop servers etc. )

So run MAMP and check 127.0.0.1:8888/magento